# Preposition "over" vs Adverb "over"

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, syntactic-analysis

> *annual growth of [**over** 7 percent]*

What do you think the part of "over" is?

Is "over" considered the preposition of the object "7 percent"?

> 1. ***over*** *[7 percent]*

Or, is "over" considered the adverb modifying the adjective "7" in front of the noun "percent"?

> 2. ***[over 7]*** *percent*

Which one is right?

Comment: You probably should not be thinking of seven as an adjective. It’s a number.  This question does not provide any background research, and it is only soliciting opinions.

Comment: OED lists it as a preposition in definition 13 under [**over**, prep. and conj.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/134248?rskey=dTmoBP&result=6#eid) *- In excess of, above, more than (a stated amount or number).* But I must say it "feels" more like an adjective in the cited context. I'd be happier calling it a preposition in, say, *Annual growth **over** the past decade has been [under/over/almost] 7%*.

Comment: John Lawler has said: _Calling something an "adverb" is a confession of ignorance._ Mind you, 'secondary modifier of quantifier' is quite a mouthful.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If cardinals are substantives, and they probably are, then that would make most of their modifiers adjectival. But that leads to oddities like somehow promoting adverbs in “Almost a thousand are ready” or prepositions in “Over a thousand is enough”. I haven’t thought about this much, but it is odd. Note though the shift in number.

Comment: Notice that both versions involve the preposition "over" (not the adverb "over"). For in both versions, the preposition "over" has a complement. For version #1, the preposition phrase is "over [7 percent]" and "7 percent" is the complement. For version #2, the preposition phrase is "over 7" and "7" is the complement. Your example is probably involving version #2. -- If you don't end up getting a detailed enough of a grammatical explanation here in EL&U land, then perhaps consider asking your question again in ELL land for a fuller grammatical explanation. :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english-thesaurus/over), *over* is here used as a preposition, not as an adverb:

> (sense 3 in preposition)
>
> *over 200,000 people live in the area*
>
> more than, above, in excess of, upwards of

*Over* is used an adverb in totally different situations:

- overhead (*birds flew  over*)
- ended (*it’s over*)
- remaining (*food left over*)

Comment: Does "preposition and its object" function as an adverbial phrase or an adjectival phrase in sentences? If so, subject position needs Noun and how could "over 200,000 people" put in the subject position?

Comment: @anotherworld That’s a good observation. If *over* is a propositional phrase whose object is *people*, doesn’t that suppose a prepositional phrase can be a noun phrase serving as the subject of a sentence? I’m not sure that works.  Certainly *live* is agreeing with plural *people*.

Comment: If *over 2000 people* is a prepositional phrase, then how come *over 2000 people* can follow a verb that only works transitively? Consider: *We have placed over 2000 people in good jobs*.   And "*we have flown over 2,000,000 people*" means ***two entirely different things*** depending on whether *over* is a preposition or not.

Comment: With substantive cardinal numbers, it seems we have an adjectival prepositional phrase, *over 200,000*, modifying *people*.

Comment: @Morgan Horse When 'adjectival prepositional phrase' modifies a noun, is it possible that the phrase position lies in front of a noun?